# Angular 6 webapp that connects to PostgreSQL using sequelize-typescript

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, angular6

I'm using Angular6, PostgreSQL and sequelize-typescript. The goal is to connect to a DB and get a list of names and ages into a table.

1. I started by creating an Express server.
2. I then used sequelize-typescript to connect to my PostgreSQL DB and call this connection when initializing server
3. I created a model of my data element using sequelize-typescript and using it to connect to my PosgreSQL DB.
4. I then created a simple route to the data using Express Router
5. I added the route to the initial Express Server
   This all seemed to work (albeit messy as I'm learning as I go). But I can reach my local server through the browser (localhost:3000) and use PostMan to get the data from the DB (localhost:3000/people).

Client side:

1. I already have the initial front-end app that was created with I ng'ed the project using command line. I can reach this at (localhost:4200)
2. I created a simple component called people using `ng g component people`.
3. How do I get the data from my server route into the client component? I believe it's through HTTP and then subscribe but there seems to be a lot of different ways to do this. I'm looking for advice on the best pattern to use in Angular6.

**TL;DR How do I get the data from my route to the front end**

Comment: After some research, I created a Service on the client side call api.service.ts. I was able to create this using ng g service api. From there, I was able to add the service to the constructor of my component, which allows me to access the api.service. The api service is a Httpclient that listens to the URL of my router. I feel like I'm getting close...now my problem is a client side error 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working correctly, I needed to create a service that listened to the API url and from there I could return the observable to the component. 
The solution (even though it's not cleaned up properly) sits at:
https://github.com/micklynch/travelbudget